# Trying to add an indicator to tabBar...but it is showing in the Wrong Place

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uiactivityindicatorview

I was trying to add a spinner to my `tabBar` (which is the 2nd tabBar in a 2 Tab TabBarController)... the following functions is called from the ViewController of the second tab bar...

```
-(UIActivityIndicatorView *)spinner {

// If we don't have a spinner, then set one up

 if (!_spinner) {

// Setup the spinner

_spinner =[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:
                   UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

// Add the spinner to the tab bar

[self.tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:_spinner];

}

return _spinner;

}
```

**The Problem is:** the activity indicator is being display (by addSubview) NOT on the respective tabBar but on the (0,0) position of my TabBarController!

Can someone please recommend some fixes!

Would really appreciate it !

Comment: did you get Tab in self.tabBarController.tabBar?? i think it will give whole tabbar rather than tab.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
 _spinner =[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:
                       UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    _spinner.center=self.tabBarController.tabBar.center;
      [_spinner startAnimating];
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:_spinner];
```